# Change google chart type using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, nette

I have this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(loadData);
    function loadData() {
        $.get({link loadData!}, function (results) {
            drawChart(results);
        });
    }
    function drawChart(results){
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        ...get some data etc...
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

and i like to change chart type using ajax. I can redraw js and html code, but function `loadData()` doesn't start again. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Run `loadData()` without `google.setOnLoadCallback()` resolved this problem